# Swift using view from other controller as the background of a uitableview

Tags: uitableview, swift

I am new to swift and am trying to create an app with a table view which can use the view from another UIView controller.

1. Is it doable?
2. If so please help me with it, I have attached my code for the main controller below. Please let me know if anything is wrong?

Thank you so much.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var numbers:[String] = []
let vc = bgViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableView.backgroundView = vc.view
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(numbers.count == 0){
        tableView.backgroundView?.hidden = false
        println("1")
    }
    else{
        tableView.backgroundView?.hidden = true
    }
    return numbers.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    return cell
}


}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create the vc like let vc = bgViewController(). Either use nibname method or instantiate through storyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created another viewController in the storyboard and change the class to bgViewController, which I created a separated file for it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var numbers:[String] = []
var vc: bgViewController!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("bgViewController") as! bgViewController

    tableView.backgroundView = vc.view
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(numbers.count == 0){
        tableView.backgroundView?.hidden = false
        println("1")
    }
    else{
        tableView.backgroundView?.hidden = true
    }
    return numbers.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    return cell
}


}
```

Provide storyboard identifier as bgViewController in attribure inspector.

Comment: Thank you very much! But this gives me an error saying class ViewController has no initializers

Comment: Converted let to var. var vc: bgViewController! Now try.

Comment: Thank you! it grabs the view of another viewController.

Comment: Just one more question, if i add a button in the other view, is it clickable in the table view?

Comment: I hope no, but still you can try.

Comment: Thank you! I have another question and can you help me with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350641/uitableview-set-a-web-view-and-a-button-outside-the-web-view-as-background

Comment: Sure,What is the question?

Comment: I have attached the link for that question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350641/uitableview-set-a-web-view-and-a-button-outside-the-web-view-as-background