# UITableView set a web view and a button outside the web view as background

Tags: uitableview, swift, background

I am new to Swift. Currently I am building an app which has a tableview as the home page. I am trying to make a graph from a website(webView) and a button as the background view of the UITableView and display it only when cell is empty.
Is it doable?
How can I combine a webView and a button and set it as the backView using 
tableView.backgroundView = (something here)?

The reason I am doing this is because I need to use the navigation controller for the segue. I have tried to put them in another view controller but then I cannot use push segue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableViewCell as a container of your button and webview. I added the mainstoryboard screenshot. 
[image]

Using custom cell in Table View explained here [Custom Cell](https://www.weheartswift.com/swifting-around/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I actually found another by simply put a web view and a button under the table view and hide the table view to make them show.